# PRISM MEF communication from viewmodel to viewmodel by using Eventaggregator in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef, eventaggregator

I am trying to create a WPF application by using WPF and PRISM. I am also using MEF and mvvm. Is it possible to have 2 viewmodels that can communicate to each other by using the event aggregastor? Eg. Publish in viewmodel A and subscribe in Viewmodel B? And if so how? I have build a program with multiple viewmodels and some of these viewmodels should communicate with each other, but somehow if I publish in Viewmodel A using a eventaggregator, A subscribe in viewmodel B will never be recognized to belong to the same eventaggregator so that I cannot update my View connected to viewmodel B.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic key steps to define Event Aggregator

(1) Create Event Agg..

public class YourEvent: CompositePresentationEvent
{

}

(2) Publisher vm

eventAggregator.Get().Publish(object);

(3) Subscription Vm

YourEvent eventobj = eventAggregator.Get();

```
    if (subscriptionToken != null)
    {
        eventobj.Unsubscribe(subscriptionToken);
    }

    subscriptionToken = eventobj.Subscribe(YourEventHandler, ThreadOption.UIThread, false, yourfun);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility is that ViewModel "B" is not loaded or has not subscribed to the event yet. If this is not true, I suggest you to paste some snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subscribing using a WeakReference (a weak subscription)? If so, and your subscriber isn't referenced elsewhere, it may be getting garbage collected and disappearing before you publish the event.

Answer (score 0):

The EventAggregator is always the same, you have to pass it of each Viewmodel. 
Prism and MEF can do this for you:

1. you can load EventAggregator in the constructor by using Unity of PRISM
2. you can inject a reference of EventAggregator with MEF

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an instance of both ViewModel "B" and ViewModel "A"?  Are you publishing the event before the subscription code has run?  Are they both publishing/subscribing to the same Event?

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent(Of MyEventType).Subscribe(Sub()

                                                   End Sub)
```